# Making a cell change to the current date and time when anything is changed

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

So I have a Storage General Arrangement for the company I work with, and we have a google sheet to make it easier to know where certain claim addresses are. Within our sheets, I want to make a cell that automatically updates to show the date and/or time when any other cell in the sheet is edited. I have been looking over the internet tyring to find a function or something that would work, but I've been unsuccessful so far.

For example, my sheet is from A1 to S80, and when any single cell is changed, a cell (I21:K22) will automically change to the current time and date without someone having to change it, as sometimes we have to deliver multiple claims within a day, and it can be forgotten, when causes confusion when I go check the garage, and the claim address that is shown to be there, isn't there, and makes the whole sheet wrong, until confirmed by me or someone else.

Comment: Hi! welcome. I think there is no way to do this with formulas only. I think you have to make an script, which is similar to a Macro in Excel. This way you can listen to an event and change the value of a formula. I have not used them a lot but here is the documentation to get you started https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1#1. I imagine the macro would be very simple as you only need to update a single cell